# Require status check on pull request, then deploy that build without rebuilding again when approved

Tags: github, travis-ci

We allow merging into `master` only via a PR and have Travis CI integrated. PRs must pass the Travis build test before being merged in, but when I merge in, it triggers a whole new build in Travis.

I'm guessing (hoping) my settings are wrong - is it not possible to have Travis run the build but not deploy (like it's doing now when the PR is created), but then when the PR is approved, just deploy from that existing build without starting a new build?

Comment: No, that's not possible. That's a good thing, because depending on when you merge the PR the result may not actually be the same as what got built on the branch. Also the build results get thrown away, unless you've specifically stored them somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe - it just doubles our build time and wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a setting.